# Only display one set of data from a loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I believe what is causing this problem is the dynamic WHERE clause I have set up. Below is how dynamic WHERE clause works:

- Compulsory WHERE condition of `q.SessionId = ?`
- If user selects single student from student drop down menu, then add `AND sa.StudentId = ?` to WHERE clause
- If user selects  `All` students option from student drop down menu, then remove or do not display `AND sa.StudentId = ?` from WHERE clause
- If user selects single question from question drop down menu, then add `AND q.QuestionId = ?` to WHERE clause
- If user selects  `All` questions option from question drop down menu, then remove or do not display `AND q.QuestionId = ?` from WHERE clause

I have three drop down menus (below is what they look like with sample data):

**Session:**

```
<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
<option value="26">POKUB1</option>
<option value="27">POKUB2</option>
</select>
```

**Student:**

```
<select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="39">Luke Mcfadzen</option>
<option value="40">Chris Tucker</option>
</select>
```

**Question:**

```
<select name="question" id="questionsDrop">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="72">1</option>
<option value="73">2</option>
</select>
```

Don't forget how the WHERE condition is suppose to work which I mentioned above in this question. Lets say the session chosen from session drop down menu is `POKUB 1, drop down value: 26`.

If you select a single student and a single question, then it displays the details correctly e.g.

- **Student:** Luke McFadzen - drop down value: 39
- **Question:** 1 - drop down value: 72

So WHERE condition is `q.SessionId = 26 AND sa.StudentId = 39 AND q.QuestionId = 72`.

But if I select an `All` option in either or both student and question drop down menu, then the output only displays one student and one question and for some strange reason it combines answers from all questions and combines all student answer answers into the single output.

Now `All` option in both drop down menus has a drop down value of `0`, now `0` is not a value to select from database but we have stated in dynamic where clause that if a `0` value is chosen from a specific drop down menu, then remove the relevant condition from the WHERE clause, so for example:

- `All` students and single question (value `72`) - `WHERE q.SessionId
  = 26 AND q.QuestionId = 72`
- Single (value `39`) student and `All` questions - `WHERE q.SessionId
  = 26 AND sa.StudentId = 39`
- `All` students and `All` questions - `WHERE q.SessionId = 26`

**THE ABOVE SCENARIOS ARE HAVING THE PROBLEMS**

If I just left the query with a static WHERE clause `WHERE q.SessionId = ?` then it outputs the details correctly if I select `All` students and `All` Questions, but I need the query to work for all different possible options selected from the drop down menus and hence why I need a dynamic WHERE clause. How can I get it to work so the correct details are outputted?

Code:

```
    $selectedstudentanswerqry = "
        SELECT
        sa.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname, q.SessionId, 
        q.QuestionId, QuestionNo, QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, 
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, QuestionMarks, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime, MouseClick, 
        (
        SELECT sum( StudentMark )
        FROM Student_Answer sta
        WHERE sa.StudentId = sta.StudentId
        AND sa.QuestionId = sta.QuestionId
        )StudentMark
        FROM Student st
        INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (st.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
        INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId) AND sa.QuestionId = sr.QuestionId
        INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
        INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
        LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
        LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
        ";

        // Initially empty
        $where = array('q.SessionId = ?');
        $parameters = array($_POST["session"]);
        $parameterTypes = 'i';


        //check if POST is empty

        // Check whether a specific student was selected
        $p_student = empty($_POST["student"])?'':$_POST["student"];

        switch($p_student){
        case 0:
            //dont' add where filters
            break;
        default:
            $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
            $parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];
            $parameterTypes .= 'i';
        }

        // Check whether a specific question was selected
        $p_question = empty($_POST["question"])?'':$_POST["question"];

        switch($p_question){
        case 0:
            //dont' add where filters
            break;
        default:
            $where[] = 'q.QuestionId = ?';
            $parameters[] .= $_POST["question"];
            $parameterTypes .= 'i';
        }

        // If we added to $where in any of the conditionals, we need a WHERE clause in
        // our query
        if(!empty($where)) {
            $selectedstudentanswerqry .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
            global $mysqli;
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
            // You only need to call bind_param once

            if (count($where) == 1) {
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0]);
        }
        else if (count($where) == 2) {
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1]);
        }
        else if (count($where) == 3) {
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1], $parameters[2]);
        }

        }

        $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
          GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
          ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
        ";

    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->execute(); 
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentId,$detailsStudentAlias,$detailsStudentForename,$detailsStudentSurname,$detailsSessionId,
    $detailsQuestionId,$detailsQuestionNo,$detailsQuestionContent,$detailsOptionType,$detailsNoofAnswers,$detailsAnswer,$detailsReplyType,$detailsQuestionMarks,
    $detailsStudentAnswer,$detailsResponseTime,$detailsMouseClick,$detailsStudentMark); 

    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->store_result();
    $selectedstudentanswernum = $selectedstudentanswerstmt->num_rows(); 

 while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch()) {

                //Check if the student data exist.
                if (!isset($questions[$detailsStudentId])) {
                    $questions[$detailsStudentId] = array(
                        'studentalias' => $detailsStudentAlias,
                        'studentforename' => $detailsStudentForename,
                        'studentsurname' => $detailsStudentSurname,
                        'questions' => array()
                    );
                }

                $questions[$detailsStudentId]['questions'][$detailsQuestionId] = array(
                    'questionno'=>$detailsQuestionNo,
                    'content'=>$detailsQuestionContent,
                    'optiontype'=>$detailsOptionType,
                    'noofanswers'=>$detailsNoofAnswers,
                    'answer'=>$detailsAnswer,
                    'replytype'=>$detailsReplyType,
                    'questionmarks'=>$detailsQuestionMarks,
                    'studentanswer'=>$detailsStudentAnswer,
                    'responsetime'=>$detailsResponseTime,
                    'mouseclick'=>$detailsMouseClick,
                    'studentmark'=>$detailsStudentMark
                );
            }

            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->close();

    foreach ($questions as $studentId => $studentData) {
        echo '<p>'.$studentData['studentalias'].' - '.$studentData['studentforename'].' '.$studentData['studentsurname'].'</p>';

        foreach ($studentData['questions'] as $questionId => $questionData) {
            echo '<p><strong>'.$questionData['questionno'].': '.$questionData['content'].'<br/>';
            echo $questionData['optiontype'].' - '.$questionData['noofanswers'].' - '.$questionData['answer'].' - '.$questionData['replytype'].' - '.$questionData['questionmarks'].'<br/>';
            echo $questionData['studentanswer'].' - '.$questionData['responsetime'].' - '.$questionData['mouseclick'].' - '.$questionData['studentmark'].'</strong></p>';
        }
    }
```

Below are the possible var_dumps for `$_POST['student']` and `$_POST['question']`:

**SINGLE STUDENT AND SINGLE QUESTION:**

- Student: Chris Tucker - string(2) "40"
- Question: 1 - string(2) "72"

**SINGLE STUDENT AND ALL QUESTIONS:**

- Student: Chris Tucker - string(2) "40"
- Question: All - string(1) "0"

**ALL STUDENTS AND SINGLE QUESTION:**

- Student: All - string(1) "0"
- Question: 1 - string(1) "72"

**ALL STUDENTS AND ALL QUESTIONS:**

- Student: All - string(1) "0"
- Question: All - string(1) "0"

Below is example `var_dump($questions);` if I select `All` students and `All` questions:

```
array(1) { 
[39]=> array(4) { 
["studentalias"]=> string(8) "u4838229" 
["studentforename"]=> string(5) "Chris" 
["studentsurname"]=> string(6) "Tucker" 
["questions"]=> array(1) { 
[72]=> array(11) { 
["questionno"]=> int(1) 
["content"]=> string(14) "What is a RAM?" 
["optiontype"]=> string(3) "A-E" 
["noofanswers"]=> int(1) 
["answer"]=> string(7) "B,C,D,E" 
["replytype"]=> string(6) "Single" 
["questionmarks"]=> int(5) 
["studentanswer"]=> string(9) "A,B,C,D,E" 
["responsetime"]=> string(8) "00:00:07" 
["mouseclick"]=> int(1) 
["studentmark"]=> string(1) "2" } } } }
```

Comment: Can you try with `-1` for `All` option instead of `0`? Also `var_dump($selectedstudentanswerqry)` before execution & check whether it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

> empty()
>   (PHP 4, PHP 5)
>
> empty — Determine whether a variable is empty Returns FALSE if var
>   exists and has a non-empty, **non-zero** value. Otherwise returns TRUE.

You might want to use other than `0` value for `All` option.

Comment: Hi sorry just had to run an errand, I'm back now, I will give your solution a try and let you know. Actually can you let me know what the value should be exactly called `value"..."` Because I assume I can't just do `value='empty'`

Comment: I meant `<option value="-1">All</option>` other than `0`. `0` == `false` in programming languages. And `empty(0)` function will return false for it.

Comment: The var_dump for $selectstudentanswerqry shows the query is performing correctly for each option , but what the output is still doing is that it is combing all student answers together as one and combines all answers as one. So if I select all students, it is displaying one student, one question but then display all answers for each question into question one and all of student's answer for each question into question one. Does that make sense?